# NHibernate left out join 3 tables

Tags: nhibernate

I have 3 entities setup in nhibernate, **user**, **album**, **photo**.
User HasMany Albums
Album HasMany Photo

I am trying to write a query in NHibernate that pretty much does the following sql query.
I want the result to be a `List<Photo>`

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how that can be done?

thanks

```
select p.* from UserTbl u
Left outer join Album a
on u.Id = a.UserId
left outer join Photo p
on a.Id = p.AlbumId
where u.Email = 'myemail@email.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need left joins there if you are starting from `User` and retrieving `Photo`.

One possibility:

```
IList<Photo> results =
    session.Query<Photo>()
           .Where(x => x.Album.User.Email = 'myemail@email.com')
           .ToList();
```